# Delete quatation marks in notepad++ regular expression

Tags: regex, notepad++

Hello i trying delete all quatation marks in notepad++

My text looks like

```
"Select * table Name
From TableName
Where SomeCondition = 1;"
```

i want get

```
Select * table Name
From TableName
Where SomeCondition = 1;

^"(Select.*.;)"
```

and it not work for me. Please help me.

Comment: Where are the parentheses in your input?

Comment: Just replace " with empty. It will work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this in the replace window of notepad++ **(ctrl + F, replace tab)**
 just enter **"** into **find what:**, leave **replace with:** empty and click **Replace All**.